Is it possible to change the default GNOME/Ubuntu lock screen function (the Lock icon in the Panel's System Menu)?
I want to change the default lock screen application to i3lock. I can invoke the i3lock application through the terminal easily enough.  But I would like to be able to use the default GNOME/Ubuntu UI and select the lock icon from the System Menu (I think it's called that -- see the image below).  There is no option that I could find using dconf (I am using X11).
Is it possible to change the default GNOME/Ubuntu lock screen function used by the Lock icon in the Panel's System Menu?



Is it possible to change the default GNOME/Ubuntu lock screen function used by the Lock icon in the Panel's System Menu?

There is no such option or config file setting because the lock screen in GNOME is not an external component; it's a built-in part of the same GNOME Shell as the panel itself.
Though it would be possible to replace just about anything by writing a GNOME Shell extension that digs sufficiently deep into the internals – e.g. by overriding the lock() method within js/ui/screenShield.js (which would then cover both the menu button and Super+L), or the activateLockScreen() method within js/misc/systemActions.js (which handles just the menu button).
